# How to download the complete project structure from cdnjs using Python

Tags: javascript, python, cdn

I want to download the complete project from the cdnjs cloud to local folder. 
I have tried this:

```
import requests
files = requests.get("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML%2CSafe.js&#038;ver=4.1")
with open("mathjax.js","w") as file:
    file.write(files.text)
```

Now this download the js file. When I tried using the same code to get the project instead of the js file, the output was weird.

So I tried using the cdnjs and check what happens when I use cdnjs cloud and when I use local file.

I have got this difference as shown in the images:

**Using cdnjs**:
[image: cdnjs output]

**Using Local file**:
[image: local output]

How I can get the similar structure as I get when I use cdnjs?
Kindly, advise me.

Comment: Why do you share the code to get a specific file and not the code that's relevant to the quest? (including the project)

Comment: It is related to the project my friend. I have shown what is happening and what I was looking for. I was not able to get the structure downloaded using the cdnjs link. Hence, I have posted a query here. If that would be that easy then I would have done it already. Why I need assistance for simplest downloading? Think about it.

Comment: Then you don't show any effort in your question.

Comment: Removing the code you have (which is of no value to what the quest is), what do we get? Nothing but two images and a challenge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL you are providing to requests module is just the URL of one file `MathJax.js`, that is why you are getting only that file as output.
What you want is to download the complete directory `mathjax/2.7.5/`. However, if we request the whole directory, the server forbids such requests.

An alternate approach is to get relative paths of all the files from the main directory, which you already have as you showed in image. You can then download each of the file independently and store it into its respective folder. You'll have the whole directory ready at the end.

Try the following code for this purpose.

```
import requests
import os

baseUrl="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/" #Base URL for the main directory
#List containing relative paths of all required files
relativePaths=['config/Safe.js?V=2.7.5',
       'config/TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML.js?V=2.7.5',
       'extensions/Safe.js?V=2.7.5',
       'jax/output/SVG/fonts/TeX/fontdata.js?V=2.7.5',
       'jax/output/SVG/jax.js?V=2.7.5',
       'MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML%2CSafe.js&#038;ver=4.1']

parentDir='\\'.join(baseUrl.split('/')[-3:]) #Parent directory from URL
for path in relativePaths: #For all files
    req=requests.get(baseUrl+path) #forming url

    filename=path.split("/")[-1].split("?")[0] #extracting filename out of url
    directory=os.path.join(parentDir,"\\".join(path.split('/')[:-1])) #Extracting directories path for local path formation
    if not os.path.exists(directory): #Creating local direcories if they do not exist
        os.makedirs(directory)

    with open(os.path.join(directory,filename),"wb+") as file: #Storing results into files
        file.write(req.content)
```

Local Directory Structure Output:

[image: Local Directory after downloading all files]

Comment: Hello Hamza, Thank you for this wonderful answer. But I am still in a dilemma. As yu have hard coded the names of the file., please can you guide me what is the possibility to check the dependencies from the MathJax.js file and download them? If you have no answer then I will wait for somebody who can answer the query in the manner I am thinking. If there is nothing then I will accept your way. But lets wait for the best.

Comment: Thanks Jaffer. You are right, there should be an approach to get the file names from js file if it is working for you elsewhere. However, I couldn't find it from within the `MathJax.js` file. Lets hope someone comes up with a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond iterating over a defined list of files, you could also look at a couple of other options that could take a more dynamic approach to fetch files from the CDN.

1. cdnjs is powered by a GitHub repository, so you could explore cloning it and extracting files (I'd recommend use sparse-checkout if you do this due to repo size) or you could look at using the GitHub API to navigate the repository an extract files: github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/tree/master/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5
2. We actually have an API available for cdnjs, which allows you to rather easily get all the files within a version of a library. Using that list, you could then perform a similar iterative solution to what Hamza suggested to get a copy of all the files locally: https://api.cdnjs.com/libraries/mathjax?fields=assets (annoyingly we've not yet implemented API navigation per version)

Hope that helps!
Matt, cdnjs maintainer.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can access files to download? I am trying `https://api.cdnjs.com/libraries/mathjax?config=Safe.js` but it is not working. Plus, is there any documentation so that I can see the keys through which what I can access?

Comment: @JafferWilson you'll want to fetch https://api.cdnjs.com/libraries/mathjax?fields=assets which will return an object with an `assets` property, an array of versions.

`assets[0]` will contain the files for the latest version, another object. The `files` property of this object is then an array of all files, with the `version` property being the version.

Iterate over `assets[0].files` and fetch `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/{assets[0].version}/{file}` for each one to get the contents.

There are limited docs: https://cdnjs.com/api
WIP new docs: https://cdnjs.dev/api